# Positioning some buttons on the top and bottom of a big div

Tags: css, layout

I have these elements:

```
<div id="button1"></div>
<div id="button2"></div>
<div id="big"></div>
```

...which need to be displayed like this:

```
|------------------|  |---------|
|                  |  | button1 |
|                  |  |---------|
|                  |
|       big        |
|                  |
|                  |  |---------|
|                  |  | button2 |
|------------------|  |---------|
```

What is the cleanest way using CSS to make the buttons align to the top and bottom of the big `div`? I want to be able to resize the big `div`. Also, the space between the big `div` and the buttons is a constant in pixels.

It's OK to add a wrapper element, but I'd prefer if I didn't have to. Anyway, I wouldn't know how to do it with the wrapper element either :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the buttons inside the "big" box:

```
<div id="big">
    <div id="button1"></div>
    <div id="button2"></div>
</div>
```

You can position the buttons relative to their container like so:

```
#big {
    position:relative;
    width:400px; height:400px;
    overflow:visible;
} #button1, #button2 {
    width:100px; height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-120px;
} #button1 {
    top:0px;
} #button2 {
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rcnbk/1/

The trick is to set the parent position:relative and the children position:absolute

Comment: how reliable is `bottom:0px`? does it work in all the browsers?

Comment: nice, it kinda works. the only thing missing is making the content that goes after all this markup to show below the thing (a footer for the whole page). `position:absolute` is making `#big` not take its space... any ideas?

Comment: oh wait it works using `relative`! (at least on firefox it does)

Comment: just add another <div id="footer"></div> after it

Comment: Yeah I meant to put relative on big... fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Create a two column layout  big div in the left column, button 1 div filler div and button 2 div in the right column.

Wrapper Tutorial: http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=A8BBA

```
|------------------|  |---------|
|                  |  | button1 |
|                  |  |---------|
|                  |  |---------|
|       big        |  | filldiv |
|                  |  |---------| 
|                  |  |---------|
|                  |  | button2 |
|------------------|  |---------|
```

Comment: If the height of big div isn't a constant, this isn't going to work

Comment: it can if the button1 filldiv and button2 are in a wrapper